# Is it possible to have a global timer running in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

For the app I am creating I would like to have a timer running in the background that can be started and stopped at any time by any file in the application.

I was wondering if this is possible, and how to go about implementing this.

I was thinking to use either a global variable (though I am unsure if this will persist between view controllers) or maybe do something with NSNotifications?

Comment: You could create a Timer class... Want me to show you?

Comment: That would be awesome if you could show me

Comment: There is probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need something like that i.e. you can access it from anywhere:

e.g.:

```
class MyGlobalTimer: NSObject {

    let sharedTimer: MyGlobalTimer = MyGlobalTimer()
    var internalTimer: NSTimer?

    func startTimer(){
        guard self.internalTimer != nil else {
            fatalError("Timer already intialized, how did we get here with a singleton?!")
        }
        self.internalTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0 /*seconds*/, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimer(){
        guard self.internalTimer != nil else {
            fatalError("No timer active, start the timer before you stop it.")
        }
        self.internalTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    func fireTimerAction(sender: AnyObject?){
        debugPrint("Timer Fired! \(sender)")
    }

}
```

It's rough, and needs a lot of work, but its functional for what I came up with in the space of 1 minute.

To access the timer you'd do something to the effect of:

```
    MyGlobalTimer.sharedTimer.startTimer()
    MyGlobalTimer.sharedTimer.stopTimer()
    let firedCounter = MyGlobalTimer.sharedTimer.numberOfTimesFired
```

*edit*

How this works is:

The `MyGlobalTimer` class is a `singleton class` which is instantiated by calling `MyGlobalTimer.sharedTimer`. This instantiates and cannot be instantiated again in the one `application instance`. From there, `[Grand Central Dispatch][1]` is used to deal with the timer and threading aspect of things.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how this works? I'm confused how you can instantiate a global timer inside of the class global timer

Comment: can you update this for swift 3 it can't find sharedTimer for some reason now

Comment: hi, I found that I'm not able to stop the timer using this code. Maybe references are changed or don't know. Can you please help?

Answer (score 16):

For anyone who needs a Swift 3 version:

```
class TimerModel: NSObject {
    static let sharedTimer: TimerModel = {
       let timer = TimerModel()
        return timer
    }()

    var internalTimer: Timer?
    var jobs = [() -> Void]()

    func startTimer(withInterval interval: Double, andJob job: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if internalTimer != nil {
            internalTimer?.invalidate()
        }
        jobs.append(job)
        internalTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: #selector(doJob), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func pauseTimer() {
        guard internalTimer != nil else {
            print("No timer active, start the timer before you stop it.")
            return
        }
        internalTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        guard internalTimer != nil else {
            print("No timer active, start the timer before you stop it.")
            return
        }
        jobs = [()->()]()
        internalTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func doJob() {
        guard jobs.count > 0 else { return }
        for job in jobs {
            job()
        }
    }

}
```

I made a few changes for my own needs. I added an `jobs` array so that I can add more actions later. And I removed those `fatalError` calls. Instead, the timer will just restart when `startTimer()` is called twice, and do nothing when `stopTimer()` is called and there is no timer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Read the NSTimer reference for building the timer.

A global variable is a global variable. It stays forever. Usually you wouldn't create just a global variable but hide all the functionality in a singleton class.

Usually it would be a good idea to say what you actually want to achieve, instead of saying what you think you need to achieve it.

Comment: So if I put an NSTimer() in a swift file outside of a class and start it, I can access it from any file and it will be the same instance?

Comment: Going the global variable route worked perfectly, thanks for suggestion.